# Solvable Lie algebra with codimension 1 ideal

Tags: lie-algebras

There is an exercise in Humphreys's *An Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory*: "Any nilpotent Lie algebra contains a codimension 1 ideal".

The proof I am thinking of is the following.

Suppose the Lie algebra $L$ satisfies $L\neq[L,L]$. Then $\pi\colon L\to L/[L,L]$ is a projection onto an abelian algebra. Choose a codimension 1 subspace $I\subset L/[L,L]$. Then $I$ is an ideal and its preimage $\pi^{-1}(I)$ is necessarily an ideal in $L$, because any subspace containing the derived algebra is an ideal. Moreover, $\pi^{-1}(I)$ has codimension 1. $\square$

The only condition on $L$ is that $L\neq[L,L]$, which holds for solvable Lie algebras as well. Is this proof correct? How come Humphreys didn't set the exercise with "nilpotent" replaced by "solvable"?

Comment: Your proof is correct and works for solvable Lie algebras. I don't know why Humphreys only set the exercise for nilpotent Lie algebras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof works indeed for all finite-dimensional solvable Lie algebras as above. 
We only need $[L,L]\neq L$. What does not work is, that every solvable Lie algebra $L$ admits a *chain of ideals*
$$
0=L_0\subseteq L_1\subset \cdots \subset L_n=L,
$$
i.e., is supersolvable. This is only true over algebraically closed fields
of characteristic zero - by Lie's theorem. So it can happen, that a solvable Lie algebra does *not* have an ideal of every possible codimension - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172389/ideals-of-solvable-lie-algebra/1172631#1172631) for an example of a real solvable Lie algebra of dimension $4$ without an ideal of codimension $3$.