# Ideals of solvable lie algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, solvable-groups

Let us say that S is a Lie algebra of dimension $n$, which is also solvable. Is it true that S contains an ideal of each dimension $d$ for $0 \leq d \leq n$? If so, how?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 4):

A Lie algebra $L$ is called *completely solvable*, or *supersolvable* if it has a chain of ideals
$$
0=L_0\subset L_1\subset \cdots L_n=L
$$ 
with $\dim L_i=i$. Over the complex numbers every solvable Lie algebra is completely solvable, hence has ideals of every dimension $0,1,\ldots ,n$. This follows from Lie's theorem. (This is no longer true in prime characteristic, or for non-algebraically closed fields of characteristic zero).

So the answer is yes for complex solvable Lie algebras, but no for real solvable Lie algebras. For example, the following $4$-dimensional solvable real Lie algebra $L$ has no $1$-dimensional ideal: $L=\langle e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\rangle$ and
$$
[e_1,e_3]=e_1,\, [e_1,e_4]=-e_2,\, [e_2,e_3]=e_2,\, [e_2,e_4]=e_1.
$$
Over the complex numbers, there is a $1$-dimensional ideal, e.g., $I=\langle e_1+ie_2\rangle$, with $i^2=-1$, but not over the real numbers.

Comment: One could also mention that there will always be ideals of those dimensions that are at least the dimension of the derived subalgebra.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The argument is the same as for the fact, that every solvale Lie algebra has an ideal of codimension $1$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374032/solvable-lie-algebra-with-codimension-1-ideal).